# Port pascal const IdentChars = ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '_']; declaration to C#

Tags: c#, delphi

I am porting a Delphi application to C#. In one of the units there is a declaration like this:

```
const
  IdentChars = ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '_'];
```

I did not found similar declaration syntax for C#.

This is the best I could come up with:

```
char[] identFirstChars; // = ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '_'];
int size = (int)'z' - (int)'a' + 1 + (int)'Z' - (int)'A' + 1 + 1; 
identFirstChars = new char[size];
int index = 0;
for(char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch = (char)((int)(ch) + 1))
{
    identFirstChars[index] = ch;
    index++;
}
for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch = (char)((int)(ch) + 1))
{
    identFirstChars[index] = ch;
    index++;
}
identFirstChars[index] = '_';
```

There must be a more efficient way.

Comment: How do you want to use it?  `char[]` is not the only option. `HashSet<char>` is another.

Comment: If the context here is that the identifier must be valid in the .net context (isvalididentifier), then maybe you shouldn't be line-for-line porting this function, you should be replacing with another similar function that is written for you already in the .NET framework... Something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.isvalididentifier.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this?

```
char[] identFirstChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_".ToCharArray();
```

Of course, you can generate an array in your code (this probably can be done with much less lines using [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)) but I think in your case it doesn't worth it.

Comment: Be aware that if C# identifiers can contain symbols other than A-Z, a-z, and 0-9, then this is not a complete set of identifier characters.  .Net allows a broad set: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 6):

IdentChars is a set, which has no direct equivalence in C# (a bit of a pain really). Secondly, IdentChars is a set of Ansi characters, not Unicode characters, so just be careful there. So, best to look at how it is used before "porting", because the functionality that you require is built into the Deplhi compiler and you will have to code this yourself in C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] ar = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_".ToArray();
```

Comment: Would be a better answer with a little explanation about the Take(53)

Comment: @Henk, its like a catch(22) but different.

Comment: You are right, there is no need for Take(53), because the string is already `IEnumerable<char>`, so the LINQ `ToArray()` method works.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient way, but at least you will not miss chars by mistake:

```
var chars =
    Enumerable.Range('a', 'z' - 'a')
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A'))
    .Select(arg => (char)arg)
    .Concat(new[] { '_' })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: It's clever, and it shows some cool stuff, but let's hope that the rest of the ported code is not going to look like this.. My eyes are hurting!

Answer (score 1):

try following,

```
 public static char[] GetConstants()
        {
            var array = Enumerable.Range((int) 'a', 26).ToList();
            array.AddRange(Enumerable.Range((int) 'A', 26));
            array.Add('_');
            return array.Select(z => (char) z).ToArray();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`char[] identFirstChars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_".ToCharArray()` is one quick and dirty way to do it ;)